# Using designated initializers for initializing a 2D char array initializer in a struct emits an error C2078 in VS2013

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, struct, designated-initializer

I'm using VS2013. The whole program is C, not C++.

I can initialize an "array of strings" like this without any problems:

```
char titles[4][80] = { "Dad", "Idiot", "Donut Lover", "Fewl" }; // OK!
```

I have a struct declared like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[80];
    char titles[4][80];
} Dude;
```

When I try to initialize the struct like this:

```
Dude homer =
{
    .name = "Homer",
    .titles = { "Dad", "Idiot", "Donut Lover", "Fewl" } // error?
};
```

I get an "error C2078: too many initializers". This is because of the array initialization- If I remove the `.titles = { ...` line, the error goes away. Why am I getting this error? Is there a different way to accomplish this type of string initialization within a struct initializer?

If I change the declaration of the struct to look like this

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[80];
    char *titles[4];
} Dude;
```

the error goes away. This is, however, not a change I can make. Other parts of the code base require that the size of this struct is exactly 400 bytes.

Further, I'm quite aware that I could use `strcpy` to fill in each field, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: try `Dude homer =
{
    "Homer", { "Dad", "Idiot", "Donut Lover", "Fewl" }
};`

Comment: AFAIK, VS2013 uses C89 and C89 doesn't support using `{ .item = … }`. (Isn't there some kind of name for that?). GCC gives `warning: ISO C90 forbids specifying subobject to initialize [-Wpedantic]` which shows that it isn't supported in C89.

Comment: I use codeblocks to compile and it is ok. I guess it is VS issue.. I updated your question to include the tags `VS` and `VS2013`

Comment: Your code is correct; it is probably a bug in VS

Comment: Never mind, I found out the name for that syntax. It is called 'designated initializers' and it seems to be implemented for VS 2013 RTM according to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/06/28/c1114-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013/)

Comment: Thanks for your research, Cool Guy- Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking that this line: `.titles = { "Dad", "Idiot", "Donut Lover", "Fewl" }` should be more like: `.titles[][80] = { {"Dad"}, {"Idiot"}, {"Donut Lover"}, {"Fewl"} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, it's easier to do this:

```
Dude homer =
{
    "Homer",
    { "Dad", "Idiot", "Donut Lover", "Fewl" } // error?
};
```

Don't know if this works, but you can try:

```
Dude homer =
{
    .name = "Homer",
    .titles[] = { "Dad", "Idiot", "Donut Lover", "Fewl" } // error?
};
```